# JavaANPR local plate recegtion (Localizing)

Tags: java, localization, ocr, automatic-license-plate-recognition

Im use to JavaANPR http://javaanpr.sourceforge.net/

I have a problem for localizing problem. I want to read Turkey plate but I getting an error not read. Why could it be. Which should I use syntax.

my xml syntax

```
<type name="turkey">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
```

Sample Turkey plates:
[image]

My result failed:
[image]

I waiting your answer. Thank you so much for help.

**UPDATE**

I solve problems
\resources\syntax.xml  did change the file
with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<structure>
<type name="turkey_2x3x2">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>

 <type name="turkey_2x2x4">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
   <type name="turkey_2x3x2">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
   <type name="turkey_2x2x36">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
    <char content=" 0123456789abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
     <char content=" 0123456789abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
  <type name="turkey_2x2x3">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>

</structure>
```

and working
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**As answered by the OP**:

---

I solve problems
\resources\syntax.xml  did change the file
with this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-2"?>
<structure>
<type name="turkey_2x3x2">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>

 <type name="turkey_2x2x4">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
   <type name="turkey_2x3x2">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
   <type name="turkey_2x2x36">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
    <char content=" 0123456789abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
     <char content=" 0123456789abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>
  <type name="turkey_2x2x3">
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="abcdefghijklmno0pqrstuvwxyz"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
   <char content="0123456789"/>
 </type>

</structure>
```

and working
[image]